# What other debug arguments are there besides NSZombieEnabled?

Tags: iphone, xcode, debugging, release, retain

I am having issues with something being released or not retained, and Xcode will not show me exactly where the error is at.

I am working collaboratively with an individual who has a horribly organized project, and I think Xcode is even freaking out, because `[CALAyer release]` is thrown, but no explanation of what or where.

Comment: Type bt (for backtrace) while the debugger is still active, most of the time you'll get a class and line number (topmost line that has them). Apologies if you're past that point.

Answer (score 2):

For env variables, you can read `NSDebug.h` (use `open -h NSDebug.h` in the Terminal). Though NSZombieEnabled is the most useful one there. If you need to debug object lifetime issues, use Instruments with the Zombies instrument. You can then see all the retain/release/autorelease events that happened for any given object.